# Bottom Sheets Dialog Fragment hide and than show after returnung from background

Tags: android, fragment, bottom-sheet

Bottom Sheets Dialog Fragment hide and then show after returning from background. Do you know how to fix this behavior? Please help.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pJ9Yh0WBnz5LSU36D-2O1dv7MR6jiH-o

https://github.com/andrefrsousa/SuperBottomSheet/tree/master/demo - This is demo

I open dialog then click Home button, app go to background, then I return to the app and see that dialog hide and then show quickly

I want to show the dialog when I return to the application without hide

Comment: Can you please attach screenshoot for clear specification

Comment: Please provide a clear explanation of what you experience, and also the code that produces incorrect behavior.

Comment: In your video the dialog doesn't hide.Then what is the problem?